# Why are succesive SVG's sized after the first one?

Tags: html

I'm trying to build a dashboard with overview of a series of build jobs from Azure.
The badges provided by Azure are rendered differently depending on the sequence of the badges.
It can be boiled down to a very simple piece of HTML, which is available [in this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/TheRoadrunner/L7w1v648/1/)

If you change the order of the three `div`'s it is obvious that the first `div` is limiting the width of the successive `div`'s.

I have tried with Chrome, Edge, Edge Beta, FireFox and IE, all with the same (mis)behaviour.

```html
<div>
  <svg width="135.0" height="20.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
          <linearGradient id="a" x2="0" y2="100%">
            <stop offset="0.0" stop-opacity="0.0" stop-color="#000" />
            <stop offset="1.0" stop-opacity="0.2" stop-color="#000" />
          </linearGradient>
          <clipPath id="c">
            <rect width="135.0" height="20.0" rx="3.0" />
          </clipPath>
          <g clip-path="url(#c)">
            <rect width="135.0" height="20.0" fill="#555555" />
            <rect width="70.8" height="20.0" fill="#4da2db" x="64.2" />
            <rect width="135.0" height="20.0" fill="url(#a)" />
          </g>
          <svg width="12" height="12" viewBox="0 0 12 12" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="5" y="4">
            <g>
              <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M0 9H1V11H3L3 12H0V9Z" fill="#fff" />
              <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd"
                d="M0.666656 4H3.7352L6.20309 0.444336C6.38861 0.166992 6.70068 0 7.03479 0H11.5C11.7762 0 12 0.224609 12 0.5V4.96484C12 5.29883 11.8332 5.61133 11.5553 5.79688L8 8.26465V11.333C8 11.7012 7.70154 12 7.33334 12H5L4 11L5.25 9.75L4.25 8.75L2.99997 10L1.99997 9L3.25 7.75L2.25 6.75L1 8L0 7V4.66699C0 4.29883 0.298462 4 0.666656 4ZM10.5 3C10.5 3.82812 9.82843 4.5 9.00003 4.5C8.1716 4.5 7.50003 3.82812 7.50003 3C7.50003 2.17188 8.1716 1.5 9.00003 1.5C9.82843 1.5 10.5 2.17188 10.5 3Z"
                fill="#fff" />
            </g>
          </svg>
  <g fill="#fff" text-anchor="middle" font-family="DejaVu Sans,Verdana,Geneva,sans-serif" font-size="11">
    <text x="41.1" y="15.0" fill="#000" fill-opacity="0.3">Short</text>
    <text x="41.1" y="14.0" fill="#fff">Short</text>
    <text x="98.6" y="15.0" fill="#000" fill-opacity="0.3">never built</text>
    <text x="98.6" y="14.0" fill="#fff">never built</text>
  </g>
  </svg>
</div>
<div>
  <svg width="155.9" height="20.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
          <linearGradient id="a" x2="0" y2="100%">
            <stop offset="0.0" stop-opacity="0.0" stop-color="#000" />
            <stop offset="1.0" stop-opacity="0.2" stop-color="#000" />
          </linearGradient>
          <clipPath id="c">
            <rect width="155.9" height="20.0" rx="3.0" />
          </clipPath>
          <g clip-path="url(#c)">
            <rect width="155.9" height="20.0" fill="#555555" />
            <rect width="70.8" height="20.0" fill="#4da2db" x="85.1" />
            <rect width="155.9" height="20.0" fill="url(#a)" />
          </g>
          <svg width="12" height="12" viewBox="0 0 12 12" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="5" y="4">
            <g>
              <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M0 9H1V11H3L3 12H0V9Z" fill="#fff" />
              <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd"
                d="M0.666656 4H3.7352L6.20309 0.444336C6.38861 0.166992 6.70068 0 7.03479 0H11.5C11.7762 0 12 0.224609 12 0.5V4.96484C12 5.29883 11.8332 5.61133 11.5553 5.79688L8 8.26465V11.333C8 11.7012 7.70154 12 7.33334 12H5L4 11L5.25 9.75L4.25 8.75L2.99997 10L1.99997 9L3.25 7.75L2.25 6.75L1 8L0 7V4.66699C0 4.29883 0.298462 4 0.666656 4ZM10.5 3C10.5 3.82812 9.82843 4.5 9.00003 4.5C8.1716 4.5 7.50003 3.82812 7.50003 3C7.50003 2.17188 8.1716 1.5 9.00003 1.5C9.82843 1.5 10.5 2.17188 10.5 3Z"
                fill="#fff" />
            </g>
          </svg>
  <g fill="#fff" text-anchor="middle" font-family="DejaVu Sans,Verdana,Geneva,sans-serif" font-size="11">
    <text x="51.6" y="15.0" fill="#000" fill-opacity="0.3">Longer title</text>
    <text x="51.6" y="14.0" fill="#fff">Longer title</text>
    <text x="119.5" y="15.0" fill="#000" fill-opacity="0.3">never built</text>
    <text x="119.5" y="14.0" fill="#fff">never built</text>
  </g>
  </svg>
</div>
<div>
  <svg width="255.9" height="20.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
          <linearGradient id="a" x2="0" y2="100%">
            <stop offset="0.0" stop-opacity="0.0" stop-color="#000" />
            <stop offset="1.0" stop-opacity="0.2" stop-color="#000" />
          </linearGradient>
          <clipPath id="c">
            <rect width="255.9" height="20.0" rx="3.0" />
          </clipPath>
          <g clip-path="url(#c)">
            <rect width="255.9" height="20.0" fill="#555555" />
            <rect width="68.9" height="20.0" fill="#4EC820" x="187.0" />
            <rect width="255.9" height="20.0" fill="url(#a)" />
          </g>
          <svg width="12" height="12" viewBox="0 0 12 12" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="5" y="4">
            <g>
              <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M0 9H1V11H3L3 12H0V9Z" fill="#fff" />
              <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd"
                d="M0.666656 4H3.7352L6.20309 0.444336C6.38861 0.166992 6.70068 0 7.03479 0H11.5C11.7762 0 12 0.224609 12 0.5V4.96484C12 5.29883 11.8332 5.61133 11.5553 5.79688L8 8.26465V11.333C8 11.7012 7.70154 12 7.33334 12H5L4 11L5.25 9.75L4.25 8.75L2.99997 10L1.99997 9L3.25 7.75L2.25 6.75L1 8L0 7V4.66699C0 4.29883 0.298462 4 0.666656 4ZM10.5 3C10.5 3.82812 9.82843 4.5 9.00003 4.5C8.1716 4.5 7.50003 3.82812 7.50003 3C7.50003 2.17188 8.1716 1.5 9.00003 1.5C9.82843 1.5 10.5 2.17188 10.5 3Z"
                fill="#fff" />
            </g>
          </svg>
  <g fill="#fff" text-anchor="middle" font-family="DejaVu Sans,Verdana,Geneva,sans-serif" font-size="11">
    <text x="102.5" y="15.0" fill="#000" fill-opacity="0.3">Very very very very long title</text>
    <text x="102.5" y="14.0" fill="#fff">Very very very very long title</text>
    <text x="220.5" y="15.0" fill="#000" fill-opacity="0.3">succeeded</text>
    <text x="220.5" y="14.0" fill="#fff">succeeded</text>
  </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: The cause of this issue is the <clipPath id="c"> which is defined by all three badges, but first one wins, when referencing <g clip-path="url(#c)">. Question is, what to do about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Badges from Azure are not intended to be displayed alongside other badges in the same context, as they make use of Id's that are not unique.

I am building a C# Razor page app, so I load the SVG's before inserting them in the Razor page.
To solve this issue, I run the SVG through this ReplaceIds method, before passing them to the Razor page:

```
    private static string ReplaceIds(string text)
    {
        string pattern = " id=\"(\\w)\"";
        while (true)
        {
            var res = Regex.Match(text, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            if (res.Success && res.Groups.Count > 0)
            {
                var id = res.Groups[1];
                Guid g = Guid.NewGuid();
                text = Regex.Replace(text, $" id=\"{id}\"", $" id=\"{g}\"");
                text = Regex.Replace(text, @$"url\(#{id}\)", $"url(#{g})");
            }
            else
                return text;
        }
    }
```